How can I determine which WM and/or desktop/UI library is being used
I want to start theming/tweaking the appearance of my Ubuntu 22.04 installation. I have activated LXQt and added a mac-lookalike theme JML_McOS in the window manager. At the moment my display manager is sddm and the window manager is xfwm4
This results in some windows getting the borders and title appearance that I expect (with the 3 colored dots at the top-left), but some are shown quite differently, for example the Window Manager dialog where I selected the Theme...
Before diving deeper into theming the window contents (colors, button look etc.), I'd first like to get all window decorations to look similar.
There's probably some other UI libraries / handlers in play here, but I am at a loss how to determine who's using what (I've heard of GTK 2 and GTK 3, but do not know if/how these impact my system at the moment.
Pointers to tutorials or explainers that deal with theming of window decorations are appreciated.
Update based on comments so far: It is clear to me now that different applications can use different UI libraries, and these may or may not support theming by the end user. So my question boils down to: how can I determine which UI library is used by each of my applications?
Is there some way to determine this reliably (preferably in a scripted/automated way) for the applications that are installed on a system?

Grepping for wm dm and lx:
jml@borg:~$ ps -ef | grep wm
jml       134843  134671  0 12:05 ?        00:00:32 /usr/bin/xfwm4
jml       211268  134671  0 13:08 ?        00:00:02 /usr/bin/xfwm4-settings
jml       224780  224744  0 13:21 pts/1    00:00:00 grep --color=auto wm
jml@borg:~$ ps -ef | grep dm
root        1231       1  0 10:09 ?        00:00:00 /usr/bin/sddm
root      133925    1231  1 12:05 tty1     00:00:55 /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg -nolisten tcp -auth /var/run/sddm/{180a65af-f401-44c7-9a7b-e38fbf126b6c} -background none -noreset -displayfd 18 -seat seat0 vt1
root      134647    1231  0 12:05 ?        00:00:00 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/sddm/sddm-helper --socket /tmp/sddm-auth01bd7d11-c282-4e26-a668-aa5ea6522d0a --id 3 --start startlxqt --user jml
jml       224784  224744  0 13:21 pts/1    00:00:00 grep --color=auto dm
jml@borg:~$ ps -ef | grep lx
root      134647    1231  0 12:05 ?        00:00:00 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/sddm/sddm-helper --socket /tmp/sddm-auth01bd7d11-c282-4e26-a668-aa5ea6522d0a --id 3 --start startlxqt --user jml
jml       134671  134647  0 12:05 ?        00:00:00 lxqt-session
jml       134807  134671  0 12:05 ?        00:00:00 /usr/bin/ssh-agent /usr/bin/im-launch startlxqt
jml       134977  134671  0 12:05 ?        00:00:03 /usr/bin/pcmanfm-qt --desktop --profile=lxqt
jml       134978  134671  0 12:05 ?        00:00:00 /usr/bin/lxqt-globalkeysd
jml       134979  134671  0 12:05 ?        00:00:00 /usr/bin/lxqt-notificationd
jml       134980  134671  0 12:05 ?        00:00:15 /usr/bin/lxqt-panel
jml       134981  134671  0 12:05 ?        00:00:00 /usr/bin/lxqt-policykit-agent
jml       134982  134671  0 12:05 ?        00:00:00 /usr/bin/lxqt-runner
jml       135371  134671  0 12:05 ?        00:00:00 /usr/bin/lxqt-powermanagement
jml       210865  134671  0 13:07 ?        00:00:00 /usr/bin/lxqt-config
jml       217080  134671  0 13:12 ?        00:00:00 /usr/bin/lxqt-about
jml       225932  224744  0 13:22 pts/1    00:00:00 grep --color=auto lx


Your details mix a number of topics that aren't really related. Lubuntu uses LXQt which is a Qt5 desktop, where LXQt doesn't have a WM involved. Lubuntu uses openbox as it's WM, from your details you're using xfwm4 from the Xfce project (fair enough!). The borders around windows are handled by the WM (as are buttons on windows) and not the desktop itself... pcmanfm-qt performs file-manager functions AND helps the LXQt desktop run (managing the background & some of the LXQt desktop you're using!)

GTK or the Gnome/Gimp toolkit isn't involved, but if you run GTK2 apps they'll use the GTK2 theme you select, likewise if you use GTK3 apps they'll use the GTK3 theme you select in the LXQt settings... They still don't cover all apps (ie. Qt apps will use LXQt settings; GTK2 use GTK2, GTK3 use GTK3 themes, but GTK4 & some snap packages still won't follow those; and your version of LXQt doesn't attempt to manage those anyway).

Thanks for the replies. To provide some context for the current setup: I come from Debian, where I used xfce for a long time, then switched to LXQt. During an upgrade (new nvidia drivers, long story) I broke my Debian installation and decided to try Ubuntu. After some failed attempts, I managed to get Ubuntu up and running (not Lubuntu!), and then started changing the setup to use LXQt and sddm again (as I was used to on Debian).

Ubuntu and Debian are essentially identical (in my view) given Debian sid is a major source (upstream) for Ubuntu development... What matters here is what software you're using (fyi: I'm a Debian & Ubuntu user too, also use many desktops; using Lubuntu now with xfwm4 myself!)... and what toolkits the software you're using will use. Gimp+GNOME Toolkit (GTK) has versions that have slowly increased; GTK4 is the development version, GTK3 in maintenance and GTK2 is EOL; so you'll have few GTK2 apps (I've only one app I'm aware of; hexchat). Debian & Ubuntu will drop GTK2 support...

the question really is when (Debian & Ubuntu work together on timing), last being dropped was Qt4 (Qt5 the Qt version in maintenance and Qt6 the development version; your older 22.04 release though will only use Qt5 I bet!). GTK4 is changing theme approach, and until it's fully laid down GTK3 theming is commonly still used by many apps... Your LXQt desktop uses Qt5 and LXQt themes; windows use xfwm themes but no doubt you're using apps intended for GTK (GNOME, Xfce, MATE, etc).  There is no single doc, but one for each library/toolkit the app uses (ie. GTK3, GTK4, Qt5 etc matters)

If you want a simple theming, the easy way is to use a desktop using one toolkit (LXQt uses Qt5 at 22.04) and limit yourself to only apps that use Qt5.. (though most of those apps will be intended for KDE Plasma anyway, where KDE also uses KF5 so even that gets messier than I want to cover)...   Sorry themes are not my area of expertise & I'm not aware of any single doc, as most of use cherry pick apps from different environments that all follow different rules/standards (ie. toolkit/libraries).  With WM, that can be easily changed (my install as 5 WMs installed) so you can experiment...

@guiverc thanks for that info, very enlightening. It's clear to me now that theming depends on more than just 1 (or 2) components, and not everything that I'd like may be possible. I will update my question to emphasise my request for help in how I can determine which application uses which UI libraries.

There is little to do about, the xfce dialog uses it's own decoration, maybe it can be themed. But you can update to a more recent version of LXQt:
https://lubuntu.me/jammy-backports-22-04-1-lxqt-1-2/

FYI: LXQt 1.2 isn't available any more, it was replaced with LXQt 1.3, then LXQt 1.4 ( https://lubuntu.me/jammy-backports-22-04-3-lxqt-1-4/ )
